# How to get public static IP of my AWS VPC?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-vpc

My services are hosted in AWS VPC. I use VPN to access my servers. For using a third party service I need to whitelist my public static IP address on their site. How can I get my public static IP address?

Comment: What kind of VPN? Site-to-site, or client?

Comment: Also, what would be talking to the third party website? You may need to give us more information about your AWS architecture.

Comment: We will make http request to the third-party server (REST backend) from our REST backend. Our backend runs on ECS.

Comment: You'll need the public IP of whatever gateway(s) ECS uses to reach the internet, so either an Internet Gateway or a NAT gateway. This will have an Elastic IP Address which is static until dissociated from the VPC (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Create a NAT Gateway, with an associated Elastic IP address. The Elastic IP is static and remains allocated to your NAT Gateway / account until you release it.

A NAT Gateway is highly available, but is within one subnet. If your solution is highly available your best option is to create an Elastic IP and NAT Gateway in each subnet, and route each subnet to the NAT Gateway in that subnet.

Give you Elastic IP address(s) to your third party service.

A cheaper solution is to use a NAT instance, but these are not highly available and need to be managed / patched / etc by you.